# Crontab quartz schedule

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cron

I want to setup a crontab expression that will start a job at every 20 mins and it will run following the time table

7-30am to 8pm Monday-Friday and 7-30am to 4pm Saturday

So far I have the following,

`0 30 7 ? * MON-FRI Fire at 7:30am every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday`

So far I have the following,

```
<schedule>
    <job>
        <name>job1</name>
        <job-class>class</job-class>
    </job>
    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>AtoZ</name>
            <job-name>AtoZ</job-name> 
            <cron-expression>0 30 7 ? * MON-FRI</cron-expression>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
</schedule>
```

I will really appreciate if someone can help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not possible. You have to schedule three separate jobs:

```
10,30,50 8-20 * * mon-fri //At minute 10, 30, and 50 past every hour from 8 through 20 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.
30,50 7 * * mon-sat //At minute 30 and 50 past hour 7 on every day-of-week from Monday through Saturday.
10,30,50 16 * * sat //At minute 10, 30, and 50 past hour 16 on Saturday.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will give it a go.

Comment: @msu if it solves your problem, feel free to upvote and mark the answer as a solution.[ask]

Comment: A little change and it's all good. Here is my solution,                                    0 10,30,50 8-20 ? * MON-FRI *

Comment: @msu happy to help. Feel free to upvote if you haven't done it yet.